# how do i add the sql date without interval

Tags: mysql, sql, days

Good Morning,

I have the following code

```html
select c.nome
from clientes as c
inner join vencimentos v on c.id = v.id_clientes
where v.data BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

He brings the records within the 30-day interval, but what I wanted him to return is only the records from the current date plus 30 days, that is, only those records that will expire in 30 days from the current date, not in the interval of 30 days from the current date.

I'm using mysql

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please tag your dbms

Comment: What's the question about this code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: I tried to add it up as data to get the records with 30 days, and we did not record in the 30-day interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` is just a date, use equality:

```
where v.data = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

If `data` has a time component, then use an inequality:

```
where v.data >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY and
      v.data < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 31 DAY and
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, it was just inserting the equality that went super well, thanks again.